# Convert row into columns with duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert SQL Server rows into columns along with it value and dates.

Here is my sample dataset:

[image]

I required it to be shown like this:

[image]

I tried case when conditions and I got this results. But I don't want to make more duplicates.

Code:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN name = 'BP' THEN value ELSE NULL AS END AS BP_value,
    CASE WHEN name = 'BP' THEN date ELSE NULL AS END AS BP_date,
    CASE WHEN name = 'Pulse' THEN value ELSE NULL AS END AS Pulse_value,
    CASE WHEN name = 'Pulse' THEN date ELSE NULL AS END AS Pulse_date
FROM 
    table_name
```

Result:

[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT
    id,
    date,
    MAX(case when name = 'BP' THEN value ELSE NULL as end) as BP_value,
    MAX(case when name = 'BP' THEN date ELSE NULL as end) as BP_date,
    MAX(case when name = 'Pulse' THEN value ELSE NULL as end) as Pulse_value,
    MAX(case when name = 'Pulse' THEN date ELSE NULL as end) as Pulse_date
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY id, date
```